# Ubuntu 18 2nd monitor detected but no signal with vga-to-dvi adapter and AMD graphics card

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, amdgpu, dvi

My setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (just upgraded, I had no problem on 16)
- VGA to DVI converter (So my 2nd monitor has vga port)
- AMD Radeon R9 285 with what I believe are the latest AMDGPU drivers
- Dell 20"IN2010N LCD monitor

I've tried rebooting several times and changing resolution, disabling and re-enabling the monitor from both xrandr and settings, and I still get the same problem.

The second monitor works fine on booting until it gets to the grub menu, the it gets no signal. If I boot to windows it works fine.

xrandr output is as follows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3520 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-1 connected 1600x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
   1600x900      59.98*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.98  
   1280x800      59.98  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      59.98  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

So it's detecting the monitor as a DVI-D-1 connection. I'm not sure why it's DVI-D here, because it's plugged into a DVI-I port.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by reverting to the previous kernel version (4.15.0-36 -> 4.4.0-93) as per [these](http://karlcode.owtelse.com/blog/2017/03/13/reverting-to-a-previous-kernel/) instructions. I'm still not sure exactly what the problem was, but now my second monitor is being picked up as DVI-I so I guess the kernel update made it misidentify that connection as DVI-D?

Comment: A bug report would be a great idea - if there was any chance anyone would do anything about it.